shell script to match a function in a file and replace it with another function in another file
I have files that contains multiple functions like below.
file1.c:
static void function1()
{
    code
}
...
static void functionX()
{
    code
}
...
static void lastFunction()
{
    code
}

file2.c:
static void function1()
{
    code
}
...
static void functionX()
{
    code is different from file1.c
}
...
static void lastFunction()
{
    code
}

In this case I'd like to find and only replace functionX() from file1.c with functionX() from file2.c and leave rest of the functions as is. The functions contain the same name ("functionX"), but the code inside of them is different. Is there a shell script command that can do this?

If you replace functionX in file1 with functionX from file2 then the result is identical to file2 so that's a bad example, please [edit] your question to provide an example we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with and get a clear pass/fail result.

Also, if functionX() can have a different number of lines between the 2 files in the real code then don't show it as having the same number of lines in your example.

This might be what you want, using any awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    $0 == "static void functionX()" { inFunc = 1 }
    inFunc {
        if ( $0 == "}" ) {
            inFunc = 0
        }
        if ( NR == FNR ) {
            buf = buf $0 (inFunc ? ORS : "")
        }
        else {
            $0 = buf
        }
    }
    (NR > FNR) && !inFunc
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file2.c file1.c
static void function1()
{
    code
}
...
static void functionX()
{
    code is different from file1.c
}
...
static void lastFunction()
{
    code
}

The above only stores the definition of functionX() from file2.c in memory, the rest of the input is processed 1 line at a time so it'll work no matter how large the input files are.

With perl:
perl -0777 -pe '
  BEGIN{
    $re =qr[(static void functionX\(\)\n\{(?s:.*?)\n\})];
    ($f) = <STDIN> =~ $re;
  }
  s/$re/$f/' < file2.c file1.c

Add the -i option to edit file1.c in-place.
